# How to remove files from Caches directory in swift 2.3?

Tags: ios, iphone, caching, swift2

The cache.db-wal file have the sensitive information in my application.Need to remove the cache files in Caches directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find a solution for the above question.

```
 func removeNetworkCache() {
        let caches = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0])
        let appId = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"] as! String
        let path = String(format:"%@/%@/Cache.db-wal",caches, appId)
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(path)
        } catch {
           print("ERROR DESCRIPTION: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you.

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first! as NSURL
let documentsPath = documentsUrl.path

do {
    if let documentPath = documentsPath
    {
        let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("\(documentPath)")

        for fileName in fileNames {

            if (fileName == "cache.db-wal")
            {
                let filePathName = "\(documentPath)/\(fileName)"
                try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(filePathName)
            }
        }

        let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("\(documentPath)")
    }

} catch {
    print("Could not clear: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

swift 4

```
func removeNetworkDictionaryCache() {
    let caches = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0])
    let appId = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"] as! String
    let path = String(format:"%@/%@/Cache.db-wal",caches, appId)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
    } catch {
        print("ERROR DESCRIPTION: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 5.2** solution (Just converted code)

```
func removeNetworkCache() {
    let caches = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0])
    let appId = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"] as! String
    let path = String(format:"%@/%@/Cache.db-wal",caches, appId)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
    } catch {
       print("ERROR DESCRIPTION: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In swift 3.1**
** In my case i wanted to remove JSON data through the folder so i named it as "fsCachedData" you can change name accordingly..**

```
func removeCache()  {

        let caches = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0])
        let appId = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"] as! String
        let path = String(format:"%@/%@/Cache.db-wal",caches, appId)
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
        } catch {
            print("ERROR DESCRIPTION: \(error)")
        }
    }
```